# Wordpress: How can I create a page template out of an existing page?

Tags: wordpress, templates

I need to apply the same content on over 4000 Wordpress pages. Now to make it as easy as possible. I create a single page and designed it with the content. So what I want to do now is create a template out of this page. Is there any possibility to export the page as php code to put it in the theme as a template? 
(It hast to be the exact content as the template file)

I am also open-minded for other Ideas to solve this problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create a template and apply your template to your pages.

With the content that you wish to apply to your pages, create a .php file. At the top of this.php (called say `page-mycontent.php`) file add this header:

```
<?php
    /* Template Name: My Template */ 
?>
```

Now the template will appear in the admin panel for `Page - Edit` on the right hand side.

### Code Changes in header.php and page.php

Your changes are in both the header and the loop. So I suggest creating two templates, one for the header and one for the body.

In your header.php, if you name your header code as header-myheader.php then pull your new header template into header.php like so:

```
<?php get_header('myheader'); ?>
```

And similarly add your body code (called mytemplate.php say) into page.php like so:

```
<?php get_template_part('mytemplate'); ?>
```

Comment: Where can I find the specific php file of my page?

Comment: Where is the shared content? e.g In the loop, the header?

Comment: The content is in the header and in the loop

Comment: ok, then it sounds as if two new templates are created, one for the header and one for the body (the loop). Is there any way to identify the 4000 pages, an author or a category for example? I mean If a page has a certain category, then apply your templates.

Comment: Yeah all pages have different names and in the content are short codes to make the pages look a little different from each other.

Comment: And the short codes are in which template? page.php?

Comment: they are in the page, which I want to create a template of

Comment: is there any way to group the 4000 pages? This is so you don't have to trawl through a 4000 page editing exercise :)

Comment: Yeah man I know haha. If you go to the Pages in Wordpress you can select all pages and bulk edit them (change the template)

Comment: I've edited answer with more info  - hope it helps.

Comment: yeah sounds good thanks, but how can I export my layout as php code 'caus I create it with advanced layout builder and I can find a way to show the source code.

Comment: the code you've create goes into your theme directory, or better still the child theme directory (if there is one).

Comment: yeah I know where to place it. But how do I export my page (which I want to use as a template) as php code, because I used an layout builder, which don't show you the php code

Comment: Can you save your page?

Comment: If you can save it as HTML you just need to add a '<?php' tag at the top of the file.

Comment: From layout builder can you see HTML at least?

Comment: Okay now I got it, but if I change the template of one page and try to view it it says, that the page is broke

Comment: Take a look at debug.log to see what is going on. I don't think my answer is of much use to you.

Comment: Okay I fixed it. We are so close to solve it thank you so much. It almost work perfect, but the shortcode doesn´t work for some reason

Comment: ok great, is the shortcode one you have created? Has the shortcode been added in functions.php?

Comment: I am using a plugin called shortcoder for this. But if I call the short code in the template with the function: <?php echo do_shortcode("[shortcode]"); ?> 
It makes the side broke

Comment: I guessing that you just need `[sc name=”your-shortcode”]` (no php tags)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197723/discussion-between-suspectus-and-chris-code).